# checking for bash

Tags: bash

Good day! Now put this task: Need to write a script that will check to see whether apache2, mysql and php and next to each item write installed or not installed.

The code please do not write! A better chew how. Yours!

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you mean by *The code please do not write!*

Comment: @kojiro Much to learn you still have.

Comment: @cnicutar thank goodness! I thought I was done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which` command and test the return value:

```
which mysql &> /dev/null || echo "mysql is not installed"
```

You can use `type` in a similar with increased portability as kojiro suggests:

```
type mysql &> /dev/null || echo "mysql is not installed"
```

Comment: Technically `which` is not standard. `type` should exist on every POSIX-compliant system, so `type -P` is a more portable answer.

Answer (score 0):

[rpm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm) with [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) can do this if your on a linux box that uses rpm as its package manager (and the packages were installed via `rpm` or an installer that uses `rpm` like `yum`):

```
[ 10:15 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ rpm -qa | grep -i "apache\|mysql\|php"
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.017-1.fc13.i686
php-pear-1.9.2-3.fc13.noarch
php-gd-5.3.6-1.fc13.i686
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Run phpinfo() function from PHP:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

This will print information about PHP, MySQL, Apache and much more.This information can be parsed if needed.